# Decimal input get rounded in create external table in Hive from CSV

Tags: sql, csv, hive, decimal

I am creating a table in Hive from a CSV (comma separated) that I have in HDFS. I have three columns - 2 strings and a decimal one (with at max 18 values after the decimal dot and one before). Below, what I do:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
col1 STRING, col2 STRING, col_decimal DECIMAL(19,18))
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION '/hdfs_path/folder/';
```

My `col_decimal` is being rounded to 0 when below 1 and to 1 when it's not actually decimal (I only have numbers between 0 and 1). 
Any idea of what is wrong? By the way, I have also tried `DECIMAL(38,37)`

Thank you.

Comment: dont want to change direction here -  can you pls bring them as string in external table and then convert them using `cast` to decimal (19,18)

Comment: This works completely fine, you are right. I just wanted to know with creating an external table with the right format does not work.

Comment: its tricky/sometime doesnt work properly so we follow above trustworthy method. But i am also looking for some answer.